# jasmine complaining about dependencies in angular module where they aren't needed

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, jasmine

I always give up on testing because I find it is more work than actually writing code that works well, but I'm working on a project I hope to open-source, so am committed to writing tests this time.

I have this angular app, and when I define it I include the dependencies

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.ace'
]);
```

When I try to test a controller, I start with

```
 beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope,$controller){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('FileSystemCtrl',{$scope:scope});
  })
  );
```

When I run jasmine, I get

```
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Failed to instantiate module ui.ace due to:
Module 'ui.ace' is not available!
```

I don't want to have to list all the dependencies every time I mock or instantiate 'app' in a test, as that would mean when I add a new dependency, I'd have to go back and change all the already existing test.

This seems very inefficient to me. 
Can somebody explain why I'm getting this error, and how to get around it?

Comment: So, somebody down voted the question. I'd love to know why. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using a test runner such as Karma, I'd highly recommend using that. [Here's the link](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html).  What karma allows you to do is to define all of your required files in one main configuration file so you can maintain it in one central location. Plus there's a jasmine plugin for karma.